# ZeroMQ PUB SUB TCP Dropping Messages Subscriber Failing

Tags: python, tcp, zeromq, pyzmq

I've built ZeroMQ from source on my Manjaro Linux machine following the instructions on the github page. All tests pass.

Basically,

```
./autogen
./configure
./make
./make install
./make check
```

I'm running the weather station example from the guide in Python, and using tcp to send/receive messages from ly laptop to my PC over my home WiFi.

Server:

```
#
#   Weather update server
#   Binds PUB socket to tcp://*:5556
#   Publishes random weather updates
#

import zmq
from random import randrange

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
socket.bind("tcp://*:5556")

while True:
    zipcode = 10001
    temperature = randrange(-80, 135)
    relhumidity = randrange(10, 60)

    socket.send_string("%i %i %i" % (zipcode, temperature, relhumidity))
```

Client:

```
#
#   Weather update client
#   Connects SUB socket to tcp://localhost:5556
#   Collects weather updates and finds avg temp in zipcode
#

import sys
import zmq

#  Socket to talk to server
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)

print("Collecting updates from weather server…")
socket.connect("tcp://192.168.1.2:5556")

# Subscribe to zipcode, default is NYC, 10001
zip_filter = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else "10001"

# Python 2 - ascii bytes to unicode str
if isinstance(zip_filter, bytes):
    zip_filter = zip_filter.decode('ascii')
socket.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, zip_filter)

# Process 5 updates
total_temp = 0
for update_nbr in range(500):
    string = socket.recv_string()
    zipcode, temperature, relhumidity = string.split()
    total_temp += int(temperature)

print("Average temperature for zipcode '%s' was %dF" % (
      zip_filter, total_temp / update_nbr)
)
```

Occasionally, messages sent from the publisher will not be detected by the subscriber, and the subscriber will sit and wait for the next message to come in. The publisher will keep sending messages, but once the subscriber fails to receive it will not receive any further messages. I've found that restarting the publisher will cause the subscriber to start receiving messages again.

I can understand a message being dropped, but can anyone explain to me why once that occurs the subscriber fails to receive further messages? Did I build this improperly?

I believe this may be a build problem because when I run the same example code in a docker based on an install with apt-get, I never lose any of the messages and it never seems to fail. I need to rebuild because I actually want to use NORM eventually.

Thanks.